# Radio Button will activate if Textbox value is equal to the radio button value

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

What I exactly want to do is that, Onload, the radio button will be active if the onload value of the Textbox is equal to the value of the radio button.

Is this possible to happen.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Please provide us with something you tried and didn't work

Comment: Thank You Guys for the suggestions, apparently, the one that i did was already working, there is only a delay from the server to send the value to the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy and simple way to use by using below concept:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('#TxtValue').val() == $('#RadioValue').val()){
$('#RadioValue').attr('checked',true)
}
else{
$('#RadioValue').attr('checked',false)
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="TxtValue" value="somevalue"/>
<input type="radio" id="RadioValue" value="somevalue"/>matched value

<input type="radio" id="RadioValue" value="somevalue1232"/>not matched value
```